# (Get / develop) a hunchback

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs

I was wondering which choice is the common way to say that in everyday English speech:

> I've been breastfeeding for almost 11 months now and my posture (which used to be great) is awful. I am always hunched and feel like I'm.................! It's totally noticeable. My husband and I both notice it.

a. **getting** a hunchback. 
b. **developing** a hunchback.

I think they both are used and mean exactly the same thing. The only thing that comes to mind is that "developing" version sounds much more formal (perhaps technical) term.

Answer (score 4):

I think that "Developing a hunchback" is the right answer. I don't think "getting a hunchback" is idiomatically correct.

When I googled the phrase "Getting a hunchback," the only thing I could find with the world "get" and "Hunchback" together was [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbGSvAEkE68) which had in its description the phrase "get rid of a hunchback," which is the opposite usage of what you are looking for.

On the other hand, I found a scientific article that uses the phrase "hunchback development," which is almost exactly what you were looking for. [Link to the article](https://www.medi.de/en/health/diagnosis-treatment/osteoporosis/dowagers-hump-hunchback/)

I think developed a hunchback is more appropriate because it references the gradual and progressive nature of the process, rather than "get" which implies instantaneous action.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! This is a good answer backed by research and evidence.

Comment: Welcome to the page and thank you for taking the time to help me Ravi, however please have a look on the following link: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+a+humchback%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enTR825TR825&oq=%22get+a+humchback%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l5.7315j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

"Hunchback" can refer to both the condition of a bent back, and the person who has that condition.

While it would be insulting to use it as a noun to mean another person, you could use it to describe yourself. So an alternative is

> ... becoming a hunchback...

If I were using "getting" or "developing", I think I'd actually say "getting a hunched back" or "developing a hunched back". Medical terms like "Scoliosis" (perhaps used incorrectly) are becoming more common as people try to avoid the "Hunchback or Notre Dame" associations of "hunchback".

Comment: But how about my own offers @James K? It's not clear of "developing" or "getting" hunchback work in this sense yet. In addition, don't you think that "hunch" stand-alone works better that "hunchback" referring to the condition of a bent back and reserve the noun "hunchback" for a who has the condition?

Comment: Thank you for the improvement James. Then may I ask you how would you use the technical term scoliosis verbally? For instance, can we say: "I'm getting / developing scoliosis"?

Comment: Also @James K, I have no idea what is wrong with "getting / developing **hunchback**" and not "**hunched** back"! Is it a matter of usage frequency or idiomatic English or what?

Comment: Developing would work better with the technical term scoliosis.  I say "used incorrectly" because a hunch is actually a kyphosis, but that term is much rarer outside of medical literature.  (Scoliosis is actually a sideways bend, not a forwards bend in the spine)

Comment: The problem with "hunchback" is that it tends to mean "the little man ringing bells in Notre Dame", or "Bad King Richard III"  rather than the condition.

Comment: Then @James K may I ask you what should one say in English in an intelligible manner and without sounding impolite for **forwards bend**? Reading between the lines "developing kyphosis" is a quite technical term which perhaps cannot be understood by the majority of people.

Comment: Perhaps "curvature in one's spine"